# Slicing Pandas Dataframe based on a value present in a column which is a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a million rows (ids) with one of the columns as a list of lists.
e.g.

> df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,4] ,'token_list' : [['a','b','c'],['c','d'],['a','e','f'],['c','f']]})

I want to create a dictionary of all the unique tokens - 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f' (which i already have as a separate list) as keys and all the ids that each key is associated with. For eg, {'a' : [1,3], 'b': [1], 'c': [1,  2,4]..} and so on.

My problem is there are 12000 such tokens, and I do not want to use loops to run through each row in the first frame. And is in does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for flattening first and then[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with `list` and last [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
a = np.repeat(df['id'], df['token_list'].str.len())
b = np.concatenate(df['token_list'].values)

d = a.groupby(b).apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)

{'c': [1, 2, 4], 'a': [1, 3], 'b': [1], 'd': [2], 'e': [3], 'f': [3, 4]}
```

Detail:

```
print (a)
0    1
0    1
0    1
1    2
1    2
2    3
2    3
2    3
3    4
3    4
Name: id, dtype: int64

print (b)
['a' 'b' 'c' 'c' 'd' 'a' 'e' 'f' 'c' 'f']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index('id')['token_list'].\
    apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(name='V').\
       groupby('V')['id'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[359]: {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [1], 'c': [1, 2, 4], 'd': [2], 'e': [3], 'f': [3, 4]}
```